# How can I create a calendar to select date ranges with tkinder?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to create a calendar to select range of months within a year or multiple years.
With these ranges, form a list to use it to select files from that period.

I leave these example images that I have found of the calendar format.

[Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xhBS.png)

The calendar must start in February 2007 and there are some months of some years that there are no data (files) so they cannot be selected.

thanks a lot for help

Comment: You should post code and showed us what you have attempted. I doubt anyone is going to just build the thing for you.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can start by creating the appropriate windows with the main window being initialized by `Tk()` and the other one with `Toplevel()`. You can use the `datetime` module to get the current year with `today = datetime.today(); year = today.year`. 3rd, you can use a `for` or `while` loop to create an array of 30 or 31 squares with the appropriate numbers (based on which month it is). And finally, you can add the year selection on the other window, using the same methods as the days and months, to change the contents of the other window.